# Grabbing values from cart variables

Tags: variables

I've just installed Livechat onto our site running Magento Community. There is an option to add custom variables into the livechat javascript so that I can obtain information about the visitors current session.
(see install help document here: http://www.livechatinc.com/kb/custom-variables-configuration/)

With very little knowledge of Magento, could anyone tell me where I might find the variable names and values that will pull in the following:

"Total Cart Value"
"Number of items in cart"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty(); ?>
```

should work